# Equivalence of measures and quotient set's cardianlity

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

So I was thinking lately how many different measures we can define on $Bor(\mathbb{R})$. My first try was to look at them as family of functions $\mathcal{M}= \lbrace\mu:Bor(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow [0,\infty]\ |\ \mu(\emptyset)=0\ \wedge\ \mu \text{ is countably additive} \rbrace$. Then we can for sure say that
$$\mathcal{M}\leq|[0,\infty]|^{|Bor(\mathbb{R})|}=\mathfrak{c}^\mathfrak{c}=2^\mathfrak{c}.$$
Then I started thinking if we can come up with better estimation. Since we're talking about "different measures" we can refer to definition of equivalence relation $\sim$ on measures:
$$\mu\sim\nu\Leftrightarrow\mu\ll\nu\ \wedge\ \nu\ll\mu$$
Where $\mu\ll\nu$ means that $\mathcal{N}_\mu\subseteq\mathcal{N}_\nu$ and $\mathcal{N}_\mu=\lbrace A:\ \mu(A)=0\rbrace$. Now we can look at this problem as finding the cardinality of quotient set $\mathcal{M}/_\sim$. Now from there we can look at few different cases:

1. $\ \mathcal{N}_\mu=Bor(\mathbb{R})$ - that's just one measure
2. $\ |\mathcal{N}_\mu|<\aleph_0$
3. $\ |\mathcal{N}_\mu|=\aleph_0$
4. $\ \aleph_0< |\mathcal{N}_\mu|<2^{\aleph_0}$
5. $\ |\mathcal{N}_\mu|=2^{\aleph_0}$

Of course by assuming Continuum Hypothesis (or Martin's Axiom I think) we can ignore the fourth case. I'm not sure if this will answer overall question about the cardinality of $\mathcal{M}$. In particular I'm not sure that equality $|\mathcal{M}|=|\mathcal{M}/_\sim|$ holds.